# How to add 2 For-Each Loops to the below code?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I need to write a program that takes 10 floating-point numbers as inputs.

The program should display the average of the numbers followed by all of the numbers that are greater than the average.

Part of my requirements include writing a method that takes an array of doubles as a parameter and returns the average of the data in the array, and I am required to use at least 2 for-each loops in this program, and am not sure where to place them.  The program works perfectly now, it just needs to have two for each loops added.

Here is what I have so far.

```
public class Floats {

    public Floats() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0, ct = 0, inc = 0, avc = 0, ac = 0, incre = 0, greaterCount = 0;
        double sum = 0, average = 0, number = 0;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] array = new double[10];
        double[] averageArray = new double[1];
        double[] greaterArray = new double[10];

        //inputs and appends to an array
        while (count < array.length) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            number = reader.nextInt();
            array[count] = number;
            sum = sum + number;
            count++;
        }
        average = sum / count;
        //counts
        while (inc < array.length) {
            if (array[inc] > average) {
                greaterArray[inc] = array[inc];
                incre++;
            }
            inc++;
        }
        //prints all numbers
        System.out.println("All of the numbers entered: ");
        while (avc < array.length) {
            System.out.print(array[avc] + "," + " ");
            avc++;
        }
        //average displayed
        averageArray[0] = average;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The average of all numbers entered: ");
        System.out.println(averageArray[0]);

        //larger than average
        System.out.println("Numbers greater than the average: ");
        while (ac < inc) {
            if (greaterArray[ac] != 0) {
                System.out.println(greaterArray[ac]);
            }
            ac++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!  Let me know if you have any questions!!

Comment: this looks like you want us to do your homework for you, anyway, ill give you a hint, for+ctrl+space.

Comment: Would [reading some documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) help?

Comment: I just noticed you have no for-loops at all.. Also, why is the average in an array of only one element?

Comment: One liner: put for(int i=0;i<1;i++){for(int j=0;j<1;j++){}} on the bottom, mate!

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to do your homework for you, but I will try to give a helpful recommendation.  The Arrays.asList(array) method returns a list that can easily be used as the source of a for-each loop.

Since it was pointed out that a for-each loop can be used on an array and a collection that implements Iterable, my answer above isn't necessary. With that in mind, I'll provide some example code:

```
String[] array = new String[] {"Test", "String", "Array"};
for (String string : array) {

}
```

Comment: But you can also do a for-each over an array. Converting to a list isn't necessary.

Comment: Good point.  I've always used for-each loops on collections that implement Iterable and forgot that they work an arrays.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation yet to comment on DarkJade's answer, but  that is not a for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Print all the numbers in `double[] array`.

```
for (double d : array) {
    System.out.print(d + ", ");
}
```

Print all the numbers in `array` greater than `average`

```
for (double d : array) {
    if (d > average) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulations, you figured it out.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, and so I gave a full answer